# loading from the storage works in the console, but not on page load

Tags: javascript

EDIT: the issue has been resolved. Apparently, the page didn't load fast enough for the id referenced to to be in place. Adding a event listener as follows solved the issue:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {stuff that's supposed to happen})
```

on my clueless journey to creating a little game I'm currently battling saving to and loading from the user's local storage. While saving appears to be working, loading doesn't, unless I manually put the respective commands into the console.

Here's the code snippet that's acting up:

```
//definition of variables

var dayLength = 10;

//if function to check if there's stored data, loading it and changing the document accordingly

if ( localStorage.saveExists === "true" ) {
    dayLength = Number(localStorage.dayLength);

    document.getElementById("displayDayLength").innerHTML = dayLength.toFixed(3);

}

var loadingAttempted = "true";

//function to save which occurs every 15 seconds (or through a button click)

function saveAuto() {
    if ( loadingAttempted === "true" ) {
        var saveExists = "false";
        
        localStorage.saveExists = "true";
        localStorage.dayLength = dayLength;
}
```

When no data are in the local storage (in other words, if saveExists = "false") the site won't attempt to load something and works as intended. The moment there is data in the local storage, the file attempts to load it (so thus far it works).

However, I'll get an error in the line supposed to change the document according to the loaded data, claiming that dayLength is "null".

If I then manually input localStorage.dayLength into the console, it returns "10", as it should. I know that storing the data into the local storage works, because otherwise the if function for loading wouldn't know (saveExists === "true") and thus not do anything. For whatever reason though, it fails to load any other data correctly and returns "null", unless I manually put the exact same code into the console.

Best part is, that I got the whole idea from another little game that does the exact same thing and there it works flawlessly.

I'm at a total loss as to why it works at the other project, but not with mine.

Educate me, if you will. And thank you in advance.

PS: I tried to use localStorage.setItem and localStorage.getItem also, but the issue remained.

Comment: Without providing a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, it is hard for anyone to help troubleshoot this without guessing

Comment: does the error happen on the line `document.getElementById("displayDayLength").innerHTML = dayLength.toFixed(3);`?If so, try **RIGHT BEFORE THAT LINE** `console.log(dayLength)` and tell me what you see

Comment: it returns 10. Now I'm beat. What is going on.

Comment: I do not understand, could u tell me the EXACT ERROR? (as in copy paste it) because if I say `document.body=null`, no errors happen.. I think it's that `document.getElementById("displayDayLength")` is `null` and trying to get `innerHTML` of `null` causes the error

Comment: 10 (this is what console.log(dayLength) returns)
endstilleScript.js:55 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at endstilleScript.js:55
(anonymous) @ endstilleScript.js:55 (this is the actual error)

Comment: Change `window.addEventListener('load', function(){})` to `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){})` and see if it works.